# MySQL COALESCE in inner join query?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, coalesce

I'm new to SQL and I have a pretty basic query:

```
SELECT role.name AS role,
       `username`,
       game.name AS favorite_game,
       `reg_date`,
       `other_game`
FROM `user` 
INNER JOIN role
ON user.role = role.rid
INNER JOIN game
ON user.favorite_game = game.gid
ORDER BY role.weight DESC, user.reg_date ASC
```

It contains three tables `user`, `role` and `game`.

In the `user` table the column `favorite_game` can be null. If this is the case I want to display the content of `other_game` instead of the name from the `game` table.

Same goes the other way around. `other_games` can be null and I want to get the name of the game.

One column always has a value so they can not be null at the same time.

How can I achieve this? I've heard about `COALESCE` but I don't know how to use it in my query and if I should.

Comment: Pls post structure of your tables (text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `coalesce` is exactly what you need. It works taking two parameters, and returns the first one if it is not null, and the second one otherwise.

From the way you wrote your query, I assume the fields without a table name as prefix are from `user` table. If that's the case, you need a `left join` with the `game` table (in case there's no row associated):

```
SELECT  tr.name AS role,
        tu.username,
        coalesce(tg.name, tu.other_game) AS favorite_game,
        tu.reg_date
FROM    user tu
JOIN    role tr
ON      tu.role = tr.rid
LEFT JOIN
        game tg
ON      tu.favorite_game = tg.gid
ORDER BY tr.weight DESC,
         tu.reg_date ASC
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: how come you can use the `favorite_game` on the `JOIN...ON` clause?

Answer (score 2):

For that, you need to `LEFT JOIN` on game twice and use `IFNULL` to select the value, e.g.:

```
SELECT role.name AS role,
       `username`,
       IFNULL(fg.name, og.name) AS favorite_game,
       IFNULL(og.name, fg.name) AS other_game,
       `reg_date`, `other_game`
FROM `user` 
INNER JOIN role
ON user.role = role.rid
LEFT JOIN game fg
ON user.favorite_game = fg.gid
LEFT JOIN game og
ON user.other_game = og.gid
ORDER BY role.weight DESC, user.reg_date ASC
```

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) the documentation for `IFNULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use case statement.

```
SELECT
role.name AS role,
`username`,
(CASE WHEN game.name IS NOT NULL THEN game.name 
WHEN game.name IS NULL THEN other_game END) AS favorite_game,
`reg_date`
FROM `user` 
INNER JOIN role
ON user.role = role.rid
INNER JOIN game
ON user.favorite_game = game.gid
ORDER BY role.weight DESC, user.reg_date ASC;
```